# R: How to sort dataframe after group_by using group_map?

Tags: r

Given that, i have a dataframe as below:

```
dt <- data.frame(year = sample(c(2000:2019),100 ),
           month = sample(c(1:12),100 ),
           paitent_ID = sample(c(1:50),100,replace = T )
```

I need to `groupby` the dataset using the `paitent_ID`  then sort each group using `year` and `month`.

Here is what i have tried:

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
  group_by(paitent_ID) %>%
  group_map( ~ order(year, month)   )
```

But, it complains with:

```
Error in order(year, month) : object 'year' not found
```

Comment: Why not just `arrange(patient_ID, year, month)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `arrange` instead of `order`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(paitent_ID) %>%
  group_map(  ~ .x %>%
                    arrange(year, month))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#   year month
#  <int> <int>
#1  2003    10
#2  2009    12
#3  2013     3
#4  2013     6

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#   year month
#  <int> <int>
#1  2000     6
#2  2000     9
#3  2006     8
#4  2009     3
#5  2015    12
#6  2017    10
#...
```